# Overview of the Linux kernel's role in Android OS

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

Can anyone provide an overview of the Linux kernel's role in Android OS?

Please share any links or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like Wikipedia provides what you're looking for in pretty plain English [right here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Design).

[Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) is basically a specialized [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) distro that sits on top of a modified [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29). There are lots of things in Android's modified kernel that are *not* in the [Linux Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) mainline (though that is [expected to change](http://www.muktware.com/news/3273/linux-33-will-let-you-boot-android-greg-kh) in Linux Kernel 3.4).

So think of the role of the Linux Kernel in Android OS as sort of like the role of the foundation of a skyscraper. Android couldn't exist without the Linux Kernel (albeit a modified version thereof).